# Разница между получением данных через Storage Access Framework и получением контента через Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, kotlin

В чем принципиальная разница между обращению к файлам на устройстве используя Storage Access Framework:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
intent.type = "image/*"
startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE)
```

И вот таким кодом:

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.type = "image/*"
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), READ_REQUEST_CODE)}
```

Я попробовал оба метода и визуальный результат одинаковый. Очень хочется понимать чем первый способ лучше второго.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` - работает с  API=1
2. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` - введен с API=19 (одновременно с SAF)

Если у вас targetSdk >=19, то оба `Intent`а будут работать одинаково, если нет, то 2-й не будет работать, только 1-й.

В совсем старых Android'ах `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` ничего не вызывал и надо было самому лепить `Activity`, который его обрабатывал. Были популярные либы, в которых был реализован обработчик `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` - [например как такой](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)

Answer (score 1):

В Android версии 4.3 и ниже для того, чтобы приложение могло получать файл от другого приложения, оно должно активизировать намерение, например, `ACTION_PICK` или `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. После этого пользователь должен выбрать какое-либо одно приложение, чтобы получить файл, а оно должно предоставить пользователю интерфейс, с помощью которого он сможет выбирать и получать файлы.

Начиная с Android 4.4 и выше, у разработчика имеется дополнительная возможность — намерение `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, которое отображает пользовательский интерфейс элемента выбора, управляемого системой. Этот элемент предоставляет пользователю обзор всех файлов, доступных в других приложениях. Благодаря этому единому интерфейсу, пользователь может выбрать файл в любом из поддерживаемых приложений.

Намерение `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` не является заменой для намерения `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Разработчику следует использовать то, которое лучше соответствует потребностям приложения:

- используйте `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, если приложению нужно просто прочитать или импортировать данные. При таком подходе приложение импортирует копию данных, например, файл с изображением.
- используйте `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, если приложению нужна возможность долговременного, постоянного доступа к документам, принадлежащим поставщику документов. В качестве примера можно назвать редактор фотографий, позволяющий пользователям обрабатывать изображения, хранящиеся в поставщике документов.